# Permission issue while working with elasticsearch keystore using CentOS?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, centos

I am a Linux noob and am trying to understand why I am running into a permissions error while sudo. I am working with Vagrant on CentOS 7 in a Virtual Box VM.

I am trying to set the initial bootstrap password for elasticsearch. I am trying to do it with the below command and not the interactive mode as I want to be able to add the command to a ansible play.

When I run the command as either the current user or with sudo

```
sudo printf "topsecret" | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add "bootstrap.password"
```

I receive the following error:

```
Enter value for bootstrap.password: ERROR: unable to create temporary keystore at [/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.keystore.tmp], please check filesystem permissions
```

Permissions of the binary:

```
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch     1954 Oct 28 20:55 elasticsearch
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      491 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-certgen
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      483 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-certutil
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      982 Oct 28 20:55 elasticsearch-cli
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      433 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-croneval
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch     2149 Oct 28 20:55 elasticsearch-env
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      121 Oct 28 20:55 elasticsearch-keystore
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      440 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-migrate
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      126 Oct 28 20:55 elasticsearch-node
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      172 Oct 28 20:55 elasticsearch-plugin
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      431 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-saml-metadata
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      438 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-setup-passwords
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      118 Oct 28 20:55 elasticsearch-shard
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      427 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-sql-cli
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 19028621 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-sql-cli-7.4.2.jar
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      426 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-syskeygen
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      426 Oct 28 20:45 elasticsearch-users
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      346 Oct 28 20:45 x-pack-env
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      354 Oct 28 20:45 x-pack-security-env
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      353 Oct 28 20:45 x-pack-watcher-env
```

permissions of the /etc/elasticsearch directory:

```
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch   232 Nov 13 01:03 elasticsearch.keystore
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch  3110 Nov 12 23:20 elasticsearch.yml
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch  2915 Nov 12 07:26 elasticsearch.yml.j2
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch  3691 Nov 12 08:46 jvm.options
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch 17545 Oct 28 20:55 log4j2.properties
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch   473 Oct 28 20:55 role_mapping.yml
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch   197 Oct 28 20:55 roles.yml
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch     0 Oct 28 20:55 users
-rwxrw-r-x. 1 root elasticsearch     0 Oct 28 20:55 users_roles
```

I know if I run

```
sudo -i
```

and then run my command I don't receive the error.

```
printf "topsecret" | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add "bootstrap.password"
```

I would like to understand why sudo -i works but sudo doesn't?
Is it possible to run this command without having to utilize sudo -i

I have followed the advice here but it did not change the outcome:

[Unable to create temporary keystore][1]

[enter link description here][2]

If you require any more information just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this out.

When I was running

```
sudo printf "topsecret" | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add "bootstrap.password"
```

`printf "topsecret"`  was executing using sudo and `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add "bootstrap.password"` was executing as a normal user.

I changed the command to the below which executed a sub shell as sudo.

```
sudo bash -c 'printf "topsecret" | /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add "bootstrap.password"'
```